# How can I get a ManagementObjectSearcher to return a ManagementObjectCollection when called asynchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wmi

Here's some code that I had, which works:

```
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver")
{
    Condition = "Name = 'FTDIBUS'"
};
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection drivers = searcher.Get();
```

But I want to call this asynchronously. I saw that there is an overload for searcher.Get() to run asynchronously, and it works by passing in a `ManagementOperationObserver` instance.

What I don't know is how to actually get it to return the same collection, though. Here's what I have so far:

```
private bool _completed = false;

public void QueryDrivers()
{
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver")
    {
        Condition = "Name = 'FTDIBUS'"
    };
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    ManagementOperationObserver results = new ManagementOperationObserver();
    results.Completed += new CompletedEventHandler(QueryComplete);
    searcher.Get(results);

    while (!_completed)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    // how do i access my ManagementObjectCollection here?
    //ManagementObjectCollection drivers = ????
}

private void QueryComplete(object sender, CompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _completed = true;
}
```

Comment: By sleeping until the result arrives, you're completely defeating the purpose of async.   Read http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: Thank you SLaks, I will read it. And while you're completely right, that doesn't address my question unfortunately.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to make a wrapper function that returns a `Task<T>` (resolved in a `Completed` handler) and `await` it.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises/

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementoperationobserver.objectready(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to ObjectReady and you will receive all your ManagementObjects there one by one:

```cs
results.ObjectReady+= Obs_ObjectReady;

...

// this will get called as many times as you have objects in the expected collection
private void Obs_ObjectReady(object sender, ObjectReadyEventArgs e)
{
   var obj = e.NewObject as ManagementObject;
}
```